# Support Japanese and Spanish text in Webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a `WebView` in which I load html page from the `res/raw resource.`

The `WebView` was not supporting `Japanese text`. Hence I read the html file and converted the text to `utf-8` and displayed it using:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL( null, readDataFromFile("res/raw/page.html"),  
                                  "text/html", "UTF-8", null );
```

The function `readDataFromFile()` reads the html file and returns String in `UTF-8` format.
This works for displaying the `Japanese text`, but fails for displaying the `Spanish` and `Danish` text.

Some `ASCII` charaters are displayed in between with the solution above.

I cannot use loadURL() as it was having problems with displaying the `Japanese text`.But was working with `Spanish` and `Danish`.

Can someone help me with a simplified solution so that i can display properly all the languages in the `WebView` correctly.

Thanks in advance,
Sneha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution myself, just convert the language specific text to utf-8 format. Once this is done it displays all the text correctly in the webview. Also save the html file in eclipse as utf-8.